# Change directive attribute from child component in Angular 2

Tags: attributes, angular

I have a parent component with the following directive `<child-component [hidden]="!visible"></child-component>`. Initially, the child component associated to this directive is hidden and after some event, I want to make it visible, so I'm using a button `<button (click)="showMe()">Show child</button>` in the parent component to change this property.

```ts
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.visible = false;
  }

  showMe() {
    this.visible = true;
  }
}
```

The problem is that, once this shows the child component, I need to provide a button `<button (click)="hideMe()">Hide</button>` in the child component to hide it again:

```ts
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private _element: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {}

  hideMe() {
    let el = this._element.nativeElement);
    this._renderer.setElementStyle(el, 'visibility', 'hidden');
  }
}
```

I'm not sure about this part but at least it works. Now, what happens if I want to change the property `hidden` of the `child-component` directive again? Calling showMe() doesn't work, presumably because of some kind of precedence in the applied styles.

What is the correct way to do this?

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MfyFGnlhfQe0OVp4H6oz): First click on 'Show child', then click on 'Hide' and then try to click on 'Show child' again. The last button clicked doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is the approach that you want, but I think it behaves like described:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  providers: [],
  host: {'[hidden]': 'hidden'},
  template: `
    <div>
      This is the child
    </div>
    <button (click)="hidden=true">Hide</button>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() hidden:boolean = false;
}
```

```ts
  <child-component #child [hidden]="true"></child-component>
  <button (click)="child.hidden=false">Show child</button>
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cRZNQZkY1gRXaMcEbDm?p=preview)

The problem in your example is that the `hidden` property and `visibility: hidden` get conflicting values.

Comment: Thank you. After reading the documentation, I think I understand what you are doing. The only problem is that I can't initiate the child component as hidden without breaking something else. Do you have a solution in that case?

Comment: I updated my answer. Just adding `[hidden]="true"` should make it initially hidden .

Comment: Of course :-) Thanks. By the way, is this the most straightforward way to accomplish communication between child and parent components?

Comment: Instead of a referring to a template variable `#child` you could refer to a field in parent (like `visible` in your example). That's the more common way, but in this example just using a direct reference in the template seemed more straight-forward.

Comment: Great. Last question: I noticed you need to add `@Input() hidden:boolean = false;`. I was assuming that @Input was another way of adding the property `input` in the `@Component` decorator, but in this case, it is referring to [hidden]="true" which is already built-in. Why do I need to inform the child component about [hidden]? It also works if I use     `inputs: ["hidden"]`.

Comment: Yes `inputs: ["hidden"]` ... `input:boolean = false;` is the same as `@Input() input:boolean = false;` just a different way of expressing it. You need the input to be able to pass values like `<child-component [hidden]="false"`>`. We could use a different name for the input but I didn't see a reason to invent a new one.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you!